# Rust - async-std's "tokio1" feature, how it works?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-async-std

There is a feature flag on async-std: [tokio1](https://docs.rs/crate/async-std/latest/features#tokio1)

```ini
async-std = { version = "1", features = ["tokio1", "attributes"] }
```

Then I can use async_std::main on tokio stuff:

```rust
#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    
    // some tokio dependent async libraries run here

    Ok(())
}
```

Basically it makes tokio dependent crates run with async-std crate.

I have two questions:

1. How does it work? (what is happening in the background?)
2. Does it affect the performance to mimic tokio libraries or it is just zero cost abstraction?

Comment: It looks like it just sets the global executor : https://github.com/async-rs/async-global-executor/blob/34f46e07e64f9422292385bfbdad55cbdca9a436/README.md?plain=1#L14

Comment: features called `tokio` are bound to `async-global-executor` dep: https://github.com/async-rs/async-std/blob/7c95bce5356ccb74e46a1a5c9f0d9a6dcb74f8c7/Cargo.toml#L58